# Best noob friendly way to clone SSD with ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, clone, cloning

I'm trying to clone an SSD with Ubuntu and some other programs on it.  I want to make an exact copy and not just copy the partition.  What's a good way to do this?  Anyone know any good youtube tutorials?  The ones I've seen only clone the partition do not actually create a bootable drive.  I have access to a windows computer I can plug drives into.  I'm brand new on Ubuntu.

Comment: I would use Clonezilla for this task. https://clonezilla.org/

Comment: I use Grsync. https://www.opbyte.it/grsync/